# Comparing values from nested dictionaries in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, comparison

I have some code that uses a nested dictionary to hold results from a linear regression. The program runs a regression on multiple sets of data ('targets'), and stores the regression variables for each target as a dictionary, and these dictionaries are contained within another dictionary using the target name as the key with the value being the dictionary holding the variables. It's initialized like this (note that `self.targets` is just a list of the different targets):

```
self.results = {}
for keys in self.targets:
    self.results[keys] = {
        'lod': '', 'p': '', 'm': '', 'b': '', 'xr': ''}
```

In another method that gets called within a for-loop, the values in the dictionary for that target are filled:

```
for tar in targets:
    ...some calculations to produce the values...
    self.results[tar].update(
        'lod': lod, 'p': p, 'm': m, 'b': b, 'xr': xr)
```

Later on, I want to plot the different regressions on one plot. To do that, I want to find the maximum value of `xr` from the sub-dictionaries (`xr` is the right-bound needed to plot each regression).

I tried accessing all the `xr` values like `self.results[:]['xr']`. That didn't work, so I pulled the `xr` values in a for-loop:

```
xrs = []
for tar in self.targets:
    xrs.append(self.results[tar]['xr'])
```

and this gets the job done, as I can just do `max(xrs)` to find the largest value. I was wondering, though, if there was a more direct way to pull the maximum value of the `'xr'` keys, without having to create a separate list as a middleman.

Comment: Is the fundamental question predicated by the ugly code associated with the throwaway list, or the space required by it?

Comment: Both, I suppose. Right now I'm focusing on eliminating ugly code and taking out 'extra' steps (like the throwaway list) where I can. Currently we're only analyzing 3-4 targets at a time, so the extra memory used up is negligible; but there may be times down the line where we'll be running much larger datasets, in which case the memory use could become an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a generator comprehension might help:

```
data = {
    "a" : {'lod': '', 'p': '', 'm': '', 'b': '', 'xr': 0},
    "b" : {'lod': '', 'p': '', 'm': '', 'b': '', 'xr': 1}
}

max_xr = max(value["xr"] for value in data.values())

print(max_xr)
```

That should give you `1` I think.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can come up with is this. You essentially do what `max()` does without filling the list (assuming `xr` is > 0, otherwise use a very negative number for `themax` like -1e-6):

```
themax = 0 # initialise maximum
for tar in self.targets:
    val = self.results[tar]['xr']
    if val > themax:
        themax = val
print(themax)
```

It will only save a minor amount of computation time at most, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! This definitely does the job; however I'm marking @JonSG's answer as the accepted one since I can just pop a single line into the code the pull the value I'm looking for - no need for conditionals/comparisons nested in for-loops. Your help is greatly appreciated though! :)